# How can I make HTTP request wait before continuing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing an extension for Google Chrome and I'm monitoring HTTP requests. In the event handler for `chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived` I'm trying to make a delay. It cannot wait asynchronously (unlike `WebExtensions` in Firefox) and it doesn't support something like `Thread.Sleep` or `CriticalSection` or `ResetEvent` or anything. The only solution that I see is spin waiting which is a very bad choice. Even synchronous `XMLHTTPRequest` is deprecated and doesn't work.

```
var headersReceived = function (e) {
    /// ?????? some method to delay synchronously
    return {cancel: false};
};

chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(headersReceived,
                                                {urls: ["*://*/*"]},
                                                ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]);
```

Comment: You can't do it in Chrome properly. Of course you can hang your extension by running a `while()` loop until `performance.now()` difference is above some number of milliseconds but that's just weird.

Comment: Synchronous XHR works, by the way. Maybe you'll need to exclude its type from your own webRequest listeners when registering, though.

Comment: @wOxxOm: Does it work in the latest version? Can you explain your second comment more?

Comment: 1) Yes of course it works. 2) You can specify which types of requests are intercepted by your webRequest listeners (see the documentation) so in case your own listener gets triggered (it shouldn't but IF it does) you can either exclude 'xmlhttprequest' or just check inside the listener if you're already sending a sync XHR (for example by using a global boolean variable).

Answer (score 0):

You can try and reference to this plugin: [network-spinner-devtool](https://github.com/gaoqing/network-spinner-devtool) it is a browser devtools extension, with capacity of URL level configuration and control, to allow introducing delay before sending http request or after receiving response(support in firefox only).

it supports both Chrome and Firefox browser

Can install from Chrome web store as well [Chrome DevTools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/network-spinner/klhfgmmihbgojnnbhdbnefjmiidlgfld)